# Negative of an ASCII photo

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

## Task

Given an \$m\times n\$ binary ascii "photo", return the negative of the photo

**Example:**

```
  #  
 # # 
#   #
 # # 
  # 
->
## ##
# # #
 ### 
# # #
## ##
```

## General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins
- [Standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) and [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/) apply
- Your output characters must be the same as your input characters (e.g. `["#"," "] -> [" ","#"]`), which you are free to choose (but must be printable characters)
- Your output photo must have the same \$m\times n\$ dimensions as the input
- Trailing whitespace is allowed

## Test cases

Input 1:

```
  #  
 # # 
#   #
 # # 
  #
```

Output 1:

```
## ##
# # #
 ### 
# # #
## ##
```

Input 2:

```
    # #
  #####
  # #  
#####  
# #
```

Output 2:

```
#### # 
##     
## # ##
     ##
 # ####
```

Input 3:

```
##############################################################################################
#  ###  ##       ##  #######  #######       ######  ###  ##       ##       ##  #######      ##
#  ###  ##  #######  #######  #######  ###  ######  ###  ##  ###  ##  ###  ##  #######  ###  #
#       ##     ####  #######  #######  ###  ######  # #  ##  ###  ##       ##  #######  ###  #
#  ###  ##  #######  #######  #######  ###  ######   #   ##  ###  ##  #  ####  #######  ###  #
#  ###  ##       ##       ##       ##       ######  ###  ##       ##  ###  ##       ##      ##
##############################################################################################
```

Output 3:

```
 ##   ##  #######  ##       ##       #######      ##   ##  #######  #######  ##       ######  
 ##   ##  ##       ##       ##       ##   ##      ##   ##  ##   ##  ##   ##  ##       ##   ## 
 #######  #####    ##       ##       ##   ##      ## # ##  ##   ##  #######  ##       ##   ## 
 ##   ##  ##       ##       ##       ##   ##      ### ###  ##   ##  ## ##    ##       ##   ## 
 ##   ##  #######  #######  #######  #######      ##   ##  #######  ##   ##  #######  ######
```

Comment: Duplicate, not sure which one

Comment: @Fmbalbuena if you can't find the duplicate then surely it isn't a duplicate?

Comment: No, but I need help of someone to find the duplicate

Comment: @Fmbalbuena yeah I did have a look, but couldn't find anything

Comment: @Fmbalbuena "well it's new to me"

Comment: I think rules are kind of blurry as any input is allowed and any input characters is valid? so that makes a 01 matrix valid input? leaving it to `|m-1|`?

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg As far as I can tell the rules say "Your output **characters** must be the same as your input **characters**", so a matrix would be disallowed

Comment: @Segan, a matrix, list, or even string has nothing to do with the requirement of being characters. None of them are themselves, they can all **contain** characters though. And yes characters can contain letters, numbers, punctuation and whitespace. So all criteria is set.

Answer (score 50):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda s:s.translate(9*"# \n ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZLNDsIgDIDvfYoGLsODF0@a@Ca7YOaiycRlcPHpcSvVYMFED@sB2tJ@6Q/jI1zubhf7YxsHezt1Fv3Bb8NknR9sODf7jdLYOlQmjtPVhaZvlFKgVxXQiPO1HJgkGSSZwk9vr0goM5PjA19StSAKfFXJY0DU8BseJbXaN@P/rh41yqJrhUl8OUqpfJt9HbHMflWZ/6YxkP9U6hRovrQYzTr5a@G0C@DegDcD3CiQ9UqE@AQ)

#### How

The `9*"# \n "` is a string that has a "\n" at position 10 which matches its own code point, and at positions 32 and 35 it has copies of "#" and " " so these two are at each other's code point. `str.translate` uses this string as a lookup table replacing each character of `s` by the value associated with its code point. It will leave newlines in place and swap hashes and spaces.

Comment: oh wow this is clever!! I dont think I would have ever thought to multiply the string like that

Comment: I'd love an explanation of how this works

Comment: @jezza the s.translate(t) function scans the characters of s and replaces each character c with the character that resides in the string t in the position asc(c), with asc the ASCII code number of the character c. What this solution does is efficiently construct a string t with \n at position 10 (which is the ASCII code of \n), a space at position 35 (which is the ASCII code of #) and a # at position 32 (which is the ASCII code of space).

Comment: The string t is constructed as 9 consecutive concatenated copies of the 4-character string “# \n “ (hash, space, newline, space). For example, there’s a \n in position 2, and after concatenation also in positions 6 and 10, and 10 is what we want. Similarly there’s a # in position 0, 4, 8 and so on through 32, and “ “ in position 3, 7, 11, …, 35.

Comment: I daresay this could save a byte by using the rule that you can define your own input/output characters (except the newline)

Comment: @Dave How? There are no printable characters before code point 32 (space) so what you gain by going for example for `!` (33) instead of `#` (35) you lose by having to use a larger (at least two digit) prefactor.

Comment: ah, I see. fair point

Answer (score 11):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>23</s> 8 bytes

-15 bytes thanks to [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)

```
y/# / #/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZIxDoAwCEV3TvETZtNLadxcjIOnRwvEVIqJDjK0lLYvn9@u0zjMyyayF0YBFxH@NYiBc6oDLGyh0SS@dVXDhf6mFW74nsqBGPBp0p6hoOEdHpGa9u34z@rBiKIzYRHfWxmTJ@9zRPX@359D2hmpn/oQ7LnVSVXUomknd568EdIVcAA)

Comment: Try `y/# / #/` :)

Answer (score 8):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), 33 bytes

Function that modifies its input.

```c
f(char*s){*s^=1^*s%3;*++s&&f(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVFLCsMgEN17iqGSoCZZlC6lVwkEQZpF0xKDm9CzW8dISYyFdpFZ6Jvfm@eomkkp5zRTt24Uhs/CtNdzK0xxkaKqTFlqZrh8uXvXD0zVlodCYeWsHyOTTaPkc@yHSbNTYQg51cJyrpnvtdjmACgA8QcF4hHQiEPcZ/Gm6KGFKNYHD2/0fB091FBYmEfDNFhATK5ATH2iScO@cwls6PesNGFM6LNgXUMSDb/RQ8qafXek/1t9@Lat6JywlH6/yhR8232eAnd/qL0B)

Answer (score 8):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 3 bytes

```
1-_
```

Maybe this is too cheaty?

- The two characters are `0` and `1`
- [Submissions may use list of strings instead of multi-line strings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/16766), so the input can be a list of rows, each of which is a string containing `0`s and `1`s
- But [Lists of decimal digits and strings that match `^[0-9]*$` are interchangeable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17167/16766), so each row can be a list of digits

The solution is a function that takes and returns a list of lists of `0`s and `1`s. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7EKNpaUlaboWiw114yGsm_bR0QbWBtaGQGwQax0NYRmC2WAxEA9NHKE-lksTYsyCBRAaAA)

Explanation: subtract each number from 1.

---

Here's a **6-byte** version that's on much safer ground rules-wise. It's also a function, and it also uses `0` and `1`, but it takes and returns a multiline string:

```
_TRt01
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7EKNpaUlaboWy-JDgkoMDCGcm4pKBgaGBgZcQMLQgAvIMjCEssHiSlyaEIULFkBoAA)

Explanation: Transliterate the characters in `10` (the `t` builtin) to the characters in `01`.

Comment: I'd say the first solution is fine, nicely done

Answer (score 8):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 25 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/./g,i=>i^1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZJNCoMwEIX3OUWXBlqd2RWKHqUYJIpFqpji9aMTQ9FJhHZhFvFlfj5exrzUpEw1tsPnNt1tfcmtyQuTjnroVKWTLM2aa5sX7ROlrfq36Tuddn2T1EkpABBALBuCWBSg12u8lPIhRNhDWaQaWq6Wqt2JvnQ67MZTF13CuUDnAVbhkxvhU98oawg718AOH1KRERk@KrY1gnn4DQ@cGr23x//t3v3MvemYMY4PR8nF0ezjCJr9uS@HnqudAQ)

Takes input as string of 0's, 1's, and newlines.

Explanation:

```javascript
s => s.replace(
  /./g,       // '.' matches anything but newline, ie. 0 or 1 only.
              // 'g' marks regex as global, to replace everything
  i => i ^ 1  // JavaScript's aggressive type casting forces '0' or '1' string into a number
              // boolean XOR (^) with 1 transforms 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0
)
```

Comment: `1-i` would also work, I assume.

Comment: @Neil, Yes that also works. Probably a bit simpler, but no byte difference so I'll keep it as is.

Answer (score 7):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 12

```bash
tr '# ' ' #'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZIxDoAwCEV3TvEThp5LJ2f1/tgCMZViokMxqZTKy@fbdTk2kXNHYZT6cBHhqUEM1FdbYGEbjS7xo7saGsZOKzzwI5UDMeDTpP@GgoZveERqOrfjf6sHI4rOhEX8aGVM3rzPEc37uTeHdDJSP/VHsOdWJ1XRiqad3HnyQUh3wAU)

Comment: Apparently you can escape the leading space instead of quoting the second string: [`tr '# ' \ #`](https://tio.run/##tZIxDoAgDEX3nuInHbiUi07O6v2rtI3BUhMd6AClwMvvh2XeV5FjQ2EUTGARHhrEwDXVARa20GgS37qr4UJ/0woPfE/lQAz4NGnPUNDwDY9ITft2/G/1YETRmbCI762MyZv3OaJ6P/bnkHZG6qc@BHtudVIVtWjayZ0nb4R0BZw)

Comment: If you used an alternative character that wasn't magic (`#` is the comment character) then you could do that with the first space too.

Comment: @ovs You can also do `tr #\  \ #`

Comment: @iBug As Neil mentioned `#` starts a comment, so this only works if you use a different character than `#`.

Comment: @ovs Totally missed that. Thanks.

Comment: if you define your characters as `t` and `r` you can use `tr rt tr`!

Answer (score 7):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 68 bytes

```lua
a=io.read('*a')b,d=a.gsub,' 'print((b(b(b(a,'#','!'),d,'#'),'!',d)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=tZJBCsIwEEXB5ZxiJItpJHbtpjsvkhKVgqjU9jRuCsVD6cqjaDJB6jSCLjqF9mfSPP789tLvW9t117bZLle3tS2qY15vrMtoYUmXxhU2353b0hDSqa4OTZaV4bKGFBmakzbOS-21cVprZkVkd5891KQFCvH18Dfk4kWogYhb7644MD7JjQ_8mKoEUeCTYvgOCA-_4VFSk3NH_N_uUaE0nTIm8eMopfiWfRrhs5-0AMJkEPIMH0JFzX0ILnyTvUNMHuIgEFaI_Kc_AQ)

[image: lol]

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 13 bytes

```matlab
@(x)['' 67-x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZK9CoMwEMd3n@IPR4kOFVRooUXoQ3QTh1J07VApvn2MSSi5M4F2MEvu@3e5y@s5PT6DHtuyLPUtn4tOKZzOx7nXB9yH94Tqkk3mrtBizE1UBnQKIEBdnQplNApU4wMlvS63LzIPqB2gFoA1jFjWengZ1oT1M8PqZ6jGoRqGol0Pm4ptkGxXcIKPCgTv@lpFwjbTGeKcbXkSpQUnKoQxfMtBV79xIMtHJyE5f7/Hbp4/I9ZhkrMdtxRS@4mXYPvZ97/1hV4A)

Takes the input as an array of `'# '` characters.

The sum of `'#'` and `' '` is 67, so all we need to do is subtract the input string from 67 and it will "negate" the characters.

Unfortunately we then have to spend a few bytes forcing the output back to being a character array rather than an integer, but ho hum.

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `pair-rocket`, 25 bytes

```
[ "# "=> " #"substitute ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcgxCsJAEEbhfk7xM1PnAoppJY2NWInFZhlhyZKVmQk5/hrE5vHx3ilHs/64T7frCcm9ZccnFRus5UUDpWFRW7XiTMSAAHREQIcgf/8@U3@CBXwZwRD2bfYosYXi1XOqFbuV0P4F)

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
⌐
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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)

Same method as DLosc's 3 byte Pip answer. Takes a list of lists of either 0 or 1.

Simply computes `1 - n` for each digit. Alternatively,

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
₀S*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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)

Takes a multiline string of 0s and 1s. The flag, header and footer are for allowing the test cases to be directly pasted in without having to change them.

### Explained

```
₀S*
₀S  # The string "10"
  * # Ring translate the input according to that - change 0 to 1, 1 to 0 and leave newlines as they are.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Each line is a separated potential program:

```
_
≠
È
```

I/O as a matrix of 1s and 0s.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8//v//6GgDHQUgMgSTBrE6CtFwniFUACoHEcOqAtWMWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaCkU@l1aLcOl5J/aQlM4H/8f5DYoW32/6Ojow10DHQMgdggVicawjIEs8FiIB6aOEI9kBNtAFMFVwliQyGSapgNcDk4HyoHNxGhYshBeKjBfQinERBZBiU0sIig6sJUi98GYuxEUoHH9cS41ZCAG/G7nngRHOYgpVjs4UBN1xsQdCvx8Y3qetqHvQESjdtOYkOMkOuJSZWEREhN96S4Apbuh26ZExsLAA).

Using the actual `#` and spaces as I/O, it would be 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) instead:

```
„# Â‡
```

I/O as multiline strings with `#`s/spaces and potential newlines.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8ZYXDTY8aFv7/r6SkpExTwKWsoACkQIQCBEA4YIDEgErBRdE0YOqECKAYj2mqMpqJaMZjZSCr4UJzA3HGK6CbitXfUONJdr2CsgK6o7E5DN14zKBEZ@AKe@xGgMKepgCYNAE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaCkU6nDpeRfWgLjufx/1DBPWeFw06OGhf91Dm2z/x@tpKCgrKAQkwcklYEUkK2gDOeB5ZR0gGpALGWwAAhAZMD6wHwwA8QHq1amKQC7EWynMthCBQgDKovEgErBRdE0YOqECKCaj2msMpqRaOZjZSCrgYQxkiuIM18B3VisPoeZT7L7wZGH6mxsLsMwHzM40Rm4wh@7EeDwpylQigUA).

**Explanation:**

```python
      # Transform each 1 to 0 and each 0 to 1 in the (implicit) input-matrix,
_     #  using an ==0 check
≠     #  or !=1 check
È     #  or %2==0 (is_even) check
      # (after which the modified matrix is output implicitly)

„#    # Push string "# "
   Â  # Bifurcate it, short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
    ‡ # Transliterate all "#" to " " and vice-versa in the (implicit) input
      # (after which the modified string is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
map g
g ' '='#'
g c=min ' 'c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzexQCGdK11BXUHdVl1ZHchKts3NzAPxk4GSmXm2BaUlwSVFPnkKKgppSgrKQBiTp6AAoUA8pf//ktNyEtOL/@smFxQAAA)

Acts on a string with newlines in it.

By the same rules-lawyering as [this Pip answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244187/3852) I guess `map$map(1-)` is a valid answer, but I don't really like it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
O^1Ọ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of lists of characters (from   and `!`) and yields a list of lists of characters with these characters swapped.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98/zvDh7p7/D3dvOdwe@f@/urp6DJeCoqKCAphQhAAIBwyQGFApuCiaBkydEAEU4zFNVUAzEc14rAxkNVxobiDOeEV0U7H6G2o8ya5XVFBEdzQ2h6EbjxmU6AxcYY/dCAUFYPQCAA)**

#### How?

```
O^1Ọ - Link: list of lists of characters
O    - ordinal (vectorises)   : ' ' -> 32  and '!' -> 33
  1  - one                    : 1
 ^   - XOR (vectorises)       : 32  -> 33  and 33  -> 32
   Ọ - character (vectorises) : 33  -> '!' and 32  -> ' '
```

---

If integers are allowed in place of characters as I/O then the one byte Link `¬` would suffice (vectorising loginal NOT).

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>38</s> 30 bytes

Or **23 bytes** by exchanging `function` for `\` using [R](https://www.r-project.org/)≥4.1: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhbbYzQqNJMzEotKijSUlBWUdJQUlJV0KjQhsjfzkhNLNNI0uJSU4YBLWQEMoExlZTAbjQmRh4jiUAtmcyHMVeLShNq6YAGEBgA)

```r
function(x)chartr("# "," #",x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQjM5I7GopEhDSVlBSUdJQVlJp0Lzf3JiiUaaBpeSMhxwKSuAAZSprAxmozEh8hBRHGrBbC6EuUpcmpr/AQ)

Comment: As of R 4.1.0 you can use a forward slash instead of "function"

Comment: @BillO'Brien - Yes, now specified, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>28</s> 22 bytes

```
,[-------[->+++<]>+.,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ1oXAqJ17bS1tW1i7bT1dGL//9cCAS6tLCDkArMB)

Switch `*`(42) and `j`(106). Long to make `\n`(10) same

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
L:::bdN\#dN\#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38fKyiopxS9GGYT/Vyop0xRwKSsoACkQoQABEA4YIDGgUnBRNA2YOiECKMZjmqqMZiKa8VgZyGq40NxAnPEK6KZi9TfUeJJdr6CsgO5obA5DNx4zKNEZuMIeuxGgsKcpUPoPAA)

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 32 bytes

Prompts for m x n matrix

```
n←(⍴m←⎕)⍴' '⋄((,m=' ')/,n)←'#'⋄n
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog APL Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tfx6QqfGod0sukAZKaQKZ6grqj7pbNDR0cm2BTE19nTxNoKS6Mkg07z9QF9f/NC5TBVOwUgVlBRBWRqXVuYA6uUCqzCGqIHIKyiCAha2goK4A0aLAZa5gaQLSpExbAHYAiFCAAGWYk1AYUClcGjB1QtUjKcY0FN0FyhgaMBl4XECc6QrohmL1NR6L8ZkOiXUUndjchcsFOBl4IgqLBhqnGGCqBgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 6 bytes

```
T`10`d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVG5DYAwDOwzxUleAHZhAJCgoKFA7A8@J0LECRIUcRGfv8vF2Zdj3aZzGCHjrK7vzM0an4AAQQ9BUARJOObVEQhDmqVZsIieERulqVGaXSh2HSJIxQdIpTvrBsrJmMjoS1ZxjI6@Cp49wWn4Rg/PWn13ov@t3v4tF10T5unLVXrwtvs6BXff1C4) Swaps `0` with `1` but link is to test suite that converts from  `#` to `01` and back. Explanation: `d` is shorthand for `0-9` or `0123456789` so this translates `1` to `0` and `0` to `1` (the extra target characters are ignored).

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
ＷＳ⟦⭆ι¬Σκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDM6@gtCS4pCgzL11DU1MhAMgo0YiGCPgmFmhk6ij45ZdoBJfmamRramrGalr//29AU8BlYGgIpECEIQRAOGCAxIBKwUXRNGDqhAigGI9pqgGaiWjGY2Ugq@FCcwNxxhuim4rV31DjSXa9oYEhuqOxOQzdeMygRGfgCnvsRoDCnrYp579uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated strings of `0`s and `1`s. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ
```

While there are more strings in the input...

```
⟦⭆ι¬Σκ
```

... logically invert each character's decimal value and output the result on its own line.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 14 bytes

-5 bytes by l4m2, using 1-m instead of abs(m-1) and +11 for providing the required function call.

```r
function(m)1-m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jV9NQN/d/mkZuYklRZoVGsoaBjgIQGYJJZLYhieIGmjoKecn5ObamQLoov1zBVsFUU/M/AA)

I do personally dislike the freedom of I/O in this challenge and allowing any other input characters than " " and "#". I learned something new from Dominic van Essen's answer actually as I was never aware of that function. But bending the rules to make life easier, nevertheless my answer. Input a 0-1 matrix and just reverse the values.

Comment: Why not `1-m`? also you need to input

Comment: yes 1-m would do, haha not sure why I made it more complex :D Anyhow, the input part what needs to be part of the count or not is perhaps my inexperience. To me it makes no sense that `function(m) 1-m` would be allowed while `1-m` would not as in both scenario's m is the input ourside.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg - You need ```function(m)1-m``` because you cannot assume that a variable named '```m```' has been defined outside your code: that would be what we call a 'snippet' (a non self-contained piece of code).

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg ...although, of course, for maximal shortness you can choose to specify R≥4.1 and change to ```\(m)1-m```...

Comment: Thanks both for the constructive feedback, I hope I managed to edit my answer to fix and give credits for the improvement.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 21 bytes

```python
lambda s:s.swapcase()
```

Takes a multiline string consisting of `a` for spaces and `A` for `#`'s and outputs the string after swapping the case of each letter. Not quite as nice-looking (or interesting) as loopy walt's wonderful answer, but I'm happy to finally write an answer to one of these :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqlivuDyxIDmxOFVD839BUWZeiUaahpKSEpcjTQGXY2IikAIRiRAA4YABEgMqBRdF04CpEyKAYjymqY5oJqIZj5WBrIYLzQ3EGZ@IbipWf0ONJ9n1iY6J6I7G5jB04zGDEp2BK@yxGwEKe5oCYNrU1ORCTqlgn3KBwxccMY5QNlgcm3JwXHBB/cYFjRkuqEe5wDyYxv8A)

Comment: Swapping case is a really clever solution to this problem!

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzv7ikSK@4PLEgObE49X9BUWZeiUaahpKSEpcjTQGXY2IikAIRiRAA4YABEgMqBRdF04CpEyKAYjymqY5oJqIZj5WBrIYLzQ3EGZ@IbipWf0ONJ9n1iY6J6I7G5jB04zGDEp2BK@yxGwEKe5oCYNrU1ORCTqlgn3KBwxccMY5QNlgcm3JwXHBB/cYFjRkuqEe5wDyYxv8A)

Comment: ... and very clever, indeed.

Comment: @loopywalt ha! you win this round...

Answer (score 3):

## [Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim), 3 bytes

```
VG~
```

> Your output characters must be the same as your input characters (e.g. ["#"," "] -> [" ","#"]), which you are free to choose (but must be printable characters)

We will use the upper case and lower case version of any alphabetic character.

#### Explanation

1. `V`: Select the whole line
2. `G`: Go to the end of the document
3. `~`: Swap case of the characters

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P8y97v//QJoCrsDCQiAFIgohAMIBAyQGVAouiqYBUydEAMV4TFMD0UxEMx4rA1kNF5obiDO@EN1UrP6GGk@y6wsDC9Edjc1h6MZjBiU6A1fYYzcCFPY0BQA) (Using: ["q","Q"] -> ["Q","q"])
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/tvpVqsr6xfqJ/OBWIp6AeCWMmJOTkKyaVFxflFGoY6Coaa/8Pc68BKC4GKIUoDgYrT/yvTFHApKygAKRChAAEQDhggMaBScFE0DZg6IQIoxmOaqoxmIprxWBnIarjQ3ECc8QropmL1N9R4kl2voKyA7mhsDkM3HjMo0Rm4wh67EaCwpykAAA) (Adding some replaces to fit the caracters in the examples)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
N
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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)

A different Vyxal solution. Expects uppercase letters for `#` and lowercase letters for   or vice versa. `N` is the swap case element. The header and footer converts the test case format into the format that the program expects and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 60 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@set s=%s: =$%
@set s=%s:#= %
@echo(%s:$=#%
@%0
```

Swaps spaces with `#`s. Doesn't work well with file input as it needs to be interrupted with Ctrl+C to exit. Explanation:

```
@set/ps=
```

Read in the next line.

```
@set s=%s: =$%
```

Replace the spaces with `$`s.

```
@set s=%s:#= %
```

Replace the `#`s with spaces.

```
@echo(%s:$=#%
```

Replace the `$`s with `#`s and output the result.

```
@%0
```

Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

## Charcoal, 19 bytes

```
ＷＳ«Ｆι«≡κ ¦#¦ »Ｍ±Ｌι¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nu3v92w@tPr9nmXndh5a/ahz4bldCoeWKR9apnBo9/s9aw9tfL9nDVBm5///CgrKCgpcQEJZgQvIUlCGsqHiIBGQmIIyCIBFQeJgHogG8WB8mgGQw8D2KYNtU4AwoJJIDKgUXBRNA6ZOiACK8ZimKqOZiGY8VgayGi40NxBnvAK6qVj9DTWeZNeDow3V0dgchm48ZlCiM3CFPXYjQGFP25QDAA)

Comment: `Ｆι←↓` saves a byte over `Ｍ±Ｌι¹`, and `≡κ#Ｍ→#` saves another byte, although it does trim spaces from the right and bottom of the output. Or I guess using `ψ` instead of `Ｍ→` works (`ψ` is the "erase" character).

Answer (score 2):

[Elisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs) + [s.el](https://github.com/magnars/s.el), 57 bytes

```
(s-replace"-""#"(s-replace"#"" "(s-replace" ""-"(read))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
f l=[[x|c<-s,x<-"# ",x/=c]|s<-l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hxzY6uqIm2Ua3WKfCRldJWUFJp0LfNjm2pthGNyf2f25iZp6CrUJuYoGvQkFpSXBJkU@egopCWrSSgoKyAlCxEpACaQLqBIog8SHysf8B)

Takes and returns a list of String

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.tr"# "," #"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulivpEhJWUFJR0lBWan2f0FRZl6JQppecmJOjoaSgoKyggIXkFBW4AKyFJShbLC4kqa2UkxeTJ4SFxe6LpC8MkgVCIBVg8wB80A0iAfSz8X1HwA)

I suggested this to fix a Ruby answer but disappeared..

Comment: Alternative of 15 bytes using `-p`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XyVer6RIUUlZQUlHSUFZ6f9/BQVlBQUuIKGswAVkKShD2WDxf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 7 characters

```
%=.;.=%
```

For this version choose the `%` and `.` characters.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZGxDoAgDER3/uPW@wHDxzgYJ/9/RK4QAwUTHegA1xYeZz2Pa08JkRsjUiJBhryAISui6lLPmwSUKqyshmXalekgloas2YOw51hEbTaitp6quzDeLIUOP1LhiA4/Fe2Z4Dx8w9NTp99d8b/d23/rTc@Mefw4Si/eZj9HaPZL4wY)

#### Gema, 10 characters

```
\#=\ ;\ =#
```

This uses the original `#` and   characters. Unfortunately this needs escaping because

- `#` is metacharacter similar to `*` (`.*` in regex), but recursive
- is metacharacter and means one or more whitespace characters (`\s+` in regex)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZGxDoAgDER3vuKS@wzDn7A4GCf/f0SuEKMFEx3oANcWHmfdt2PNOTEmLAmROQMEQlmIUBTYdK2XTYJKFVZWwzLtynSQU0PW7EHac6iiNW@ita6qu9DfrIUHvqfSER1@KO5ngvPwDQ9PHX53w/92b//taXpkzOP7UXrxNvsxQrOfGic)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
5\Zc
```

Input is a char matrix containing   and `#`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zQmKvn//2h1ZZoCdWsFdWUFBSALRChAAIQDBkgMqBRcFE0Dpk6IALoNmAYroxmKZgNWBrIaqA3ILiHOBgV0g7H6HmEDyX5QUFZAdzo2t2GxATNY0Rm44gG7EdB4oG1aigUA)

#### How it works

```
     % Implicit input
5\   % Modulo 5 of (codepoints) of the input chars. This gives 2 for space, 0 for '#'
Zc   % Convert nonzeros to '#' and zeros to char(0)
     % Implicit display. char(0) is displayed as a space
```

Comment: Congrats on 100k rep!

Comment: @Steffan Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (PCRE2), 19 bytes

```
s/(#)| /${1:+ :#}/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVbhd5pIEP/uXzFqXwQlNbHXXs6N6TNKEu9Q8xCuSWvLQ1wNr4g@wCa9mH/9csMuEEDt3X0oHxRm5/eb2ZnZnbFWq8O5ZT2Xp3RmuxSuO6rcMDrDrmzog55mfOh1tSs4KZRt13LWUwqnK8ujjdd3ZwXrzvTAWH36DC1QS@f3918nb9a337/faHfv7u@EZ78ulMUN1F89Hjdr0Cw/1efPYl6tJEF11TJWJGXBD6b2MrSQFnm2O8/K7CVKqbnY1jsr2G4AK3wNDOp5S0@wlq4fAPO4uqC@b86p@Ih2mk0LFeD0FCJp@Mrk1J06BDwarD0XjskThJT@dzcwHyJO8TFaTRsqjZgKsK@SSJ62XAm/reWUivBYAHyYU5H1T4237z4TJrZnILBQG3MaQY1ISwjhEgg8V3rnqq2eVMVoUQLf/osuZ0K8TajHkpS@KIrMSvhkwlBiStz9JpT2Roahk@gUnng1TKljL1pHBCbLpYMR80w3dDdcciX2Z/K/SRK8NcbjxAgE99AU4bSVfE/wm0S0VSzNqcHIOVnVj6M3W3ogEOLXarEkDl4xVIqMDHRFIckqdXzKVKp@q1UZjysI5YhaLYd52g1iriSaPqd@KvBkL0zbFWJvGKJWWxVbFb@y2RQFHqJQJL4QZMqKMBDTOz3abOIoMoH0y4n09kTMSTdvGtJvv0rHjbe4gkfAusNCfCWI1drr07P3X0oS9zexlynYnvvNdOwpz50d0LBqAd0jL9VZ9fGIp3Kwinws@nu3UMWMYGyPKmmaWZbGj2lm@2lmGZqwON40jACWrSMs9CXy8aIe6ecjrafpmmzIN5o86Mpd2Gyv6YORrBly/1q7JanyQTOYn7FbITALC8m/twPrDhM3Sw6pidmvzCvN0Ohmh9VLZXjeVgiqTvBO@kpSqDaiIIVqDzpXQ1XuEkg9Wyg5j1KU4QfuutFR2qPRiy2o18Fa@8FyAYdgOs7yHvBSNt0pfPryGRz7KwW502@PLM9eBSkTN1smNON8pN/scCxjgrrmxKEwXsNYZ2YwihadQuNwas/tAMYPKSOdHUY6PbWj9y8UOTa1w4jtQn0BC3bTfRl/RDYXTxamJcVt57g77ZGsyDw0@yPbzaG6Q0VpqwYWzXCg3JI9KH8LpWFKMpZ2oH7Po/TrQbsv/4uHDzlUXNI/Rg1yqH5b61xFJX/e7vyhyhdkV6QH151LH0wr@EGpLPLcuqL1lN5AJj/yyM2hBkOjrWtDzNO1pqsRdgu1zqH0znVylnXtYg9Kz6MGl6osd2/3xQznHXPtBM1c@5N544svxZljznkXxMtr32hQSLooHz@wdlfrgHARdm8HByuBm7Fdia9KEN5qIveF9/mwq0PVoyT6ZtWOUjegDwGOLelPwsYRj/q4BYl3axJfSr2PMpPMZj7FxeU6cKg7D@4IpAaAaiifrGdxI8ebNPZisbIdKkTTwuhaU8WVFEE/yurQ0GS13xu0NbmL5BIcMOvRf2TzSHwZYooe3dl42G@kl91qa1cADBSZARVi6mRbqM4i@jqccrDnNWrHqbs96Rh2a@vOHv4pqxfhrarIg0vtipD0CMHDg@TpsakqCja8R3fxkrWExAURmrjDRIi4VNhF8WXy4AlLNuivJ35gB2vclvcy0LGQ8y1ZBlaUIEqZHWJ4UQA1bEXsNROmLIu/P3GRmwcvfpLM@BS5etbCZKbPTbxuw8FBvJ9iclGp6lDFY96X@0P1dmfaOSRnrGjHNjBPR/E4xZJ47@FMsh1VCY6l8IChAMeEmUdjncyRylYQ08qIRJI6e3wdqzU52@jJ03P5pz6FMgD@hT9RPPgHe1Iv0VIizQG2kVyQod9mLecYc/Q7X9I6hZwP/40e8qw79x3R/2/voQx5p3c5lqffDmX@ZV/sd1OEsf@pz99W2Jz850OHlfDhyT8)
[Try it on regex101!](https://regex101.com/r/vOcJPl/1)

This is a single regex substitution, to be applied once.

In this explanation, `␣` indicates a space:

```
s/         # Match the following:
    (#)    # \1 = match one "#"
|          # or
    ␣      # match one space
/          # Replace with the following:
${1:+␣:#}  # If \1 is set, replace with a space, else replace with "#"
/g         # Enable Global replacement flag
```

## Regex (Boost), 15 bytes

```
s/(#)| /?1 :#/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVRdb5swFH3nV9wk04CENmm7bh2EVpq0h0nVHvYhbVo35IAhqGAQNkuikv30Zf4gKSFh2h5qRcG@957j43uv7ef5SeT7m0FM/KQMMExnWUbZuMARXp7O8/xa8@eoAC//9h1c@NB/s1jczy7Kr6vVl0/zl4u5saFjY2BWML45A3swjjZmO6RvwTB3vdzRHneJ@SYFRum1FhMGecH/PVwUWWH4GaEM5KbDFFOKImw@UBbYts8DYDqF2iqm0o5JkDhQYFYWBM6cNQhKuiIMLWtO86H2Njfqf5QhIFd901mrkwY4iVN34gBPRMKpCkQibEgXseQHqc9sx1py0iuPGeQEmTB1d@sZX29ph2FMAk@SK7IhNeFBAz7CrADDcehotLWIEYdg9ERQvcn7z7e3zs6LE4plyJC6rn53p3OoQoxGLcz6OEhK2UVSRb3W1rIgKYqJsVUjEaNR3nN1qldVz1ApEibzkWAv344EybjppKq2WZQG68WVdXlltqzVxbn1@pV1dn7JPbw3/Dmv0DPDHI5Op9c3P/qW0rvbb6@S78hPlMSBql3MsCgncHnqUHW6efs2apDXGnu08whDXhGe24nepAn3aeiWJuymCfdoRHNcnHsMMs4kL5tty9tm2yTz0izwUgdQyTKgjQjeIyliXhgXlHkZSVZQtVwoSZxGO/Fteb3uiO5AKBqLLmLmz3khw21ZfcS7QY91G7iUyoWWmFj4HdU4M35V750GinahhH7ahVr@DbXsQqUK9dyFX13pOoKKOIruoQ5S6DRRAQ5RmTAb9p6a/ltRRRu2DRYmKIK@8PBG6Hp/lAr5jDUF8wgjtyDjLSFhvMljEvEXJi@Z0iDNEWZJTLChdMTEUhEWiBYyG4F@VjKhobmHV@A8QT42akyBLaD8l9XAWuTE0dabwZMObQDAP@Kvfn3UQo7GpHbtrC3AIVIZ9ugPWQctxhb90UkzRmtp@Dd6aLMePXdN/9/qYQBt0ceEtekPU9medOX@OIXI/ZOO3764ZXRzksjO9mRj/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 6 bytes

```
⍜(⊛♭)¬
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4o2cKOKKm-KZrSnCrAoKRiBbIiAgIyAgIgogICAiICMgIyAiCiAgICIjICAgIyIKICAgIiAjICMgIgogICAiICAjICAiXQo=)

What it does is flatten `♭` the input, convert it to binary `⊛`, logical not `¬` it, unbinary it back to characters, then assume the original shape. Under `⍜` is the modifier that handles all the function inverses.

Or, using [Jordan's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271826/97916),

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 1 byte

```
¯
```

Just swapcase, but unlike the first answer the letters used must be lower/upper case of the same letter.

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__WyJhYUFhYSIKICJhQWFBYSIKICJBYWFhQSIKICJhQWFBYSIKICJhYUFhYSJdCsKvCg==)

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 9 bytes

Uses `A` and `a` (or any letter and its swapped-case counterpart) as the “pixels.”

```ruby
:swapcase
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWK62KyxMLkhOLUyH8m_oFpSXFCm7RNjaufi6xXImJjomJXEDCMZELyEp0hLIh4kAlEG0LFkBoAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
†?_aD¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDAvv4RJdD2/7//@@Y6MiV6JjIBaQB)

Input & output as single multiline string; 'pixels' are 'A' and 'a' (or any other pair of uppercase & lowercase letters).

Split on newlines (`¶`), then, for each (`†`) character, if (`?`) it's uppercase (`D`) convert to lowercase (`_`), otherwise convert to uppercase (`a`).

If input is already list of strings, we can drop the `¶` for **[5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDAvv4RJf///9HKzkmOirpKCU6JgJJEDsWAA)**.
If input is a list of integers (1 and zero) we can have **[2 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDgkNr/v//Hx1tqGOgYxirEw0kdQyANIQfCwA)**.

Comment: After running some tests, I can definitively say its all just yelling at me.

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 55 bytes

```
/
 /
> //
#/
>#// #/ >#//# /#> //>#/->//> /#>//-/ //>//
```

Man, the underscore on the /// link looks bad.  Ah, well.

Basically, we first put a cursor (>) before every run of hashes or spaces, then flip each character after a >.  We need to use an intermediate character (-) to avoid flipping things twice.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVKxDcMwDNt5BQHNAT/ILx0KdMjm/@FaslGksgO0QzREFGMTFJNyPMrrWWoVKOyUYK2bRBO9G2XON7ztrfkobXJKqnZrwcjW/MFefYg6gfHqw6YL881OfMnPqpYUk/wSnM8gefhNnll1ufeQ/9s9jdn0yliWn6PM4Cr7tYRnf@@fg9gMkWd8CBu48wgXTnbvGMljLIKYyPoG)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 70 bytes

```rust
|s:&str|->String{s.replace("#","?").replace(" ","#").replace("?"," ")}
```

This replaces all occurrences of `#` with `?`, replaces all   with `#`, and then all `?` with  . It's quite an effective algorithm.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZBBDoIwEEX3nOI7TQxN0ANI9BKegBgwJNiQtq4oZ69FiOJQE10wi3b62//yO/purK8UbkWtUomuKS0qHOGdOWyN1W53Oltdq2tn9rpsm@JSpiQoI0fyLSAIYi64IIBk73O0wW0btUmp6ylDFeyrViKAsA0LxhoPz5o109VLZYalcxQ@8EuqYESGjzbzNwnL8BsenBr994T/Oz0EeOhYMI5fjpI332YfRwyzX7VIyrz3Dw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 2 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 1.65 bytes

```
ZX
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLoiIgDCh_wS2mBeqONAUxeY6JiUAaRCRCAIQDBkgMqBRcFE0Dpk6IAKr5mMYiM7CYj5WBrAZsPrIriDM_Ed1YrD6HmU-y-xMdE9Gdjc1lGOZjBic6Ay18kJ2NRQM4_GkK1CEpFQA)
or [see it with `#` and](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSn1LsgqWlJWm6FouiIiCMdVHhxlqORtrOXkaWzlGZEMEFt5gWqDvSFMTkOSYmAmkQkQgBEA4YIDGgUnBRNA2YOiECqOZjGovMwGI-VgayGrD5yK4gzvxEdGOx-hxmPsnuT3RMRHc2NpdhmI8ZnOgMtPBBdjYWDeDwpylQh6RUAA)

Port of Seggan's Vyxal answer. Uses `a` and `A` as the two characters.

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `N`, \$ 10 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 8.23 bytes

```
A\Ziedi1_J
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSn1LsgqWlJWm6FqscY6IyU1MyDeO9IAJQ8QW3mBaoG9IUxOQZGhgAaRBhAAEQDhggMaBScFE0DZg6IQKo5mMaa4hmJJr5WBnIasDmI7uCOPMN0I3F6nOY-SS738DQAN3Z2FyGYT5mcKIzcIU_diPA4U9ToA5JqQA)
or [see it with `#` and](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSn1LsgqWlJWm6FqscY6IyU1MyDeO9IAJrUjLVlbVSHePrXPWgQgtuMS1QN6QpiMkzNDAA0iDCAAIgHDBAYkCl4KJoGjB1QgRQzcc01hDNSDTzsTKQ1YDNR3YFceYboBuL1ecw80l2v4GhAbqzsbkMw3zM4ERn4Ap_7EaAw5-mQB2SUgE)

Uses `0` and `1` as the two characters.

##### Explanation

```python
ZX  # Implicit input
ZX  # Swap case of input
    # Implicit output
```

```python
A\Ziedi1_J  # Implicit input
A\          # Push a newline
  Zi        # Split the input on newlines
    e       # Map over this list:
     di     #  Convert each character to an integer
       1_   #  Subtract each from one
         J  #  Join the resulting list
            # N flag joins on newlines
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I/O as an array of binary strings.

```
mèT
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=behU&input=WwoiMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMSIKIjEwMDExMTAwMTEwMDAwMDAwMTEwMDExMTExMTEwMDExMTExMTEwMDAwMDAwMTExMTExMDAxMTEwMDExMDAwMDAwMDExMDAwMDAwMDExMDAxMTExMTExMDAwMDAwMTEiCiIxMDAxMTEwMDExMDAxMTExMTExMDAxMTExMTExMDAxMTExMTExMDAxMTEwMDExMTExMTAwMTExMDAxMTAwMTExMDAxMTAwMTExMDAxMTAwMTExMTExMTAwMTExMDAxIgoiMTAwMDAwMDAxMTAwMDAwMTExMTAwMTExMTExMTAwMTExMTExMTAwMTExMDAxMTExMTEwMDEwMTAwMTEwMDExMTAwMTEwMDAwMDAwMTEwMDExMTExMTEwMDExMTAwMSIKIjEwMDExMTAwMTEwMDExMTExMTEwMDExMTExMTEwMDExMTExMTEwMDExMTAwMTExMTExMDAwMTAwMDExMDAxMTEwMDExMDAxMDAxMTExMDAxMTExMTExMDAxMTEwMDEiCiIxMDAxMTEwMDExMDAwMDAwMDExMDAwMDAwMDExMDAwMDAwMDExMDAwMDAwMDExMTExMTAwMTExMDAxMTAwMDAwMDAxMTAwMTExMDAxMTAwMDAwMDAxMTAwMDAwMDExIgoiMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMSIKXS1S)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 63 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVO7bsMgFN39FUdmMCyRmmyWqNQPyFR1ijpQ146oHGoZGqlK8@0uAas1GFfpkDsgONx7DtyHrkQrhveXt7oy2AqpcBpe6wYN1eWj6aXaM65XB9HRit/Lxq68IAUrUNStrjEisAjxSMUG4MJwsGRU9Htd4qHvxefO0z2zEk9KGnCcMlg7ihZSdR/mDtwBQJ7n5KY26gBfBLDnyzIi/uBsshmvftAoYB7pgbTOnJ5E1JFOcjP1CXSmr7pOBzF9MhOxzr//A4L4G6kXLurM0x1vluqTpgjqc1OzDb3Stv27rR0IqbKw8dfTxndJ@X2XK05YXrJ462L/1tqEWq74AUE4HmNzRHkKAFfVtGpnB960ijbUDzhjAcxSTutrnDbO6Zyds@Eb)

```scala
def f(s:String)=s.map(c=>if(c=='#')' 'else if(c==' ')'#'else c)
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZOxTsMwEIb3PMWveEiyVKLdkILEA3RCTIjBmKQKSt0oTiuhkmcPh23AdhxUht4Qnf@c77N9d0rwlk@Hl7dKDNjyRuI8Aa9VjTpXt3gY@kbuim8HJdRqzzucE5AJripkLEN5hwyZo8FozNEEOaQJUkaL2BMv5/2OQPd9z9@fDOWZeI@yGYhmOCfeopHdcbhBqQUgTVN2VbMc4IMBtP76WMUstDmO/fWjBhvmO40Q58zTsyB1wIk6bozHcU91GQdh@uhLhJx/3wcM4TViJ1zkzJ87dJbqE0/h1eeqRg29UtT@3ZYGopGJ3/hrt/H1o/yeSxfHLy9b/Kv3/s3a@CxdfC@BPx62OYJ38gRd1Ti1o4EfWpnXuRnwovDkIha0viRoo4PGZEymTw)

```scala
def f(s: String): String = s.map {
  case '#' => ' '
  case ' ' => '#'
  case c   => c
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 11 bytes

```
'# '{~'#'&=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxWl1ZQb26Tl1ZXc0WIrJdkys1OSNfIU3BLrm0xMdNobgkJTNPXR0iu-AW0wxlmgIuZQUFIAUiFCAAwgEDJAZUCi6KpgFTJ0QAxXhMU5XRTEQzHisDWQ0XmhuIM14B3VSs_oYaT7LrFZQV0B2NzWHoxmMGJToDV9hjNwIU9jQFkBQKAA)

```
'# '{~'#'&=
      '#'&=  NB. vectorized equality check, returns boolean matrix
    {~       NB. index into
'# '         NB. inverted char list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 7 bytes

```perl
y; #;#
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoieTsgIzsjICIsImFyZ3MiOiItcCIsImlucHV0IjoiICAjICBcbiAjICMgXG4jICAgI1xuICMgIyBcbiAgIyAgIn0=)

### Explanation

Uses the `tr`ansliteration syntax (`y///`) but using the implicit `;` from `-p` (`-n`: `while (<STDIN>) {`...`;}`).

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 7 bytes

```
" #"@^:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#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)

- `^:` check which characters in the input are nulls (i.e. spaces/`" "`)
- `" #"@` flip the characters by indexing into `" #"` (0's become  s, 1's become `#`s)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.9, 38 bytes

```swift
let f={($0+[]).map{($0+[]).map{1-$0}}}
```

`f(_:)`'s type is `([[Int]]) -> [[Int]]`. The two "characters" are `1` and `0`.