# Convert To Shorthand Part 1

Tags: code-golf, unicode, substitution

This challenge has been divided into parts.
Your goal is to convert a sentence into a form of 'short-hand'

### For Part 1 these are the rules

1. Take in 1 word
2. Remove all vowels(a,e,i,o,u), except the ones at the beginning and the end
3. If a letter is repeated more than once consecutively, reduce it to only one (e.g. `Hello` -> `Hlo`)
4. Create a function which converts the word into it's corresponding unicode characters based on above given rules, as given in the table

| Letter | Corresponding Unicode Character |
| --- | --- |
| A | Λ |
| B | L |
| C |  |
| D | Ꙅ |
| E | ∟ |
| F | ⌽ |
| G | T |
| H | | |
| I | ⩗ |
| J | ) |
| K | < |
| L | ( |
| M | ᨈ |
| N | ᑎ |
| O | ┼ |
| P | ⊥ |
| Q | ⩁ |
| R | \ |
| S | ⦵ |
| T | _ |
| U | ⋃ |
| V | ⌵ |
| W | ⌵ (same as V) |
| X | X |
| Y | ɥ |
| Z | ᒣ |

### Test Cases

| English Word | Substituted Word |
| --- | --- |
| A | Λ |
| Quick | ⩁< |
| Brown | L\⌵ᑎ |
| Fox | ⌽X |
| Jumps | )ᨈ⊥⦵ |
| Over | ┼⌵\ |
| The | _|∟ |
| Lazy | (ᒣɥ |
| Dog | ꙄT |
| Turtle | _\_(∟ |
| Of | ┼⌽ |
| Terror | _\ |

As this is code-golf, shortest answer wins!

Part 2 has been posted [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/246641/106829)

Comment: Can we return a list of codepoints instead?

Comment: @Steffan No, the output must be only be composed of the symbols given

Comment: Do `pop` => `pp` or `p` or either?

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 86 bytes

```
zzgn"aeiou"XX\\)**97?-"ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ"jsi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V8d7qIb@7@qKj1PKTE1M79UKSIiJkZTS8vS3F5X6dxsnw8TejtfzWx51DH/Uc/ekJpHK6dr2mg8XNHxcGLfoyl7HnUtfbSyMebRsq3xj7qbH/VsBaKIk0sfTlqslFWc@b823Od/YGlmcjYnUBXIJBsup6L88jxOnxigQqARXG75FZxAgyO4vEpzC1JTODWBRgMNBdrI5V@WWsQJsqNnaw1XSEYqZ3wNl09iVSWnBtD4k0u5XPLTOYHqQgA)

```
zz          # To lower case
gn          # Unique consecutives
"aeiou"XX   # Vowels as list
\\          # List diff
)**         # Map ord
97?-        # Conert to index into alphabet
"ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ" # SH as string
jsi         # Select indices from SH string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 151 bytes

```python
lambda s:R(r"(.)\1+",r"\1",R("\B[AEIUO]\B","",s.upper())).translate(4*'ᑎ┼⊥⩁\⦵_⋃⌵⌵XɥᒣΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈ')
import re
R=re.sub
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKkijSElDTzPGUFtJp0gpxlBJJ0hDKcYp2tHVM9Q/NsZJSUdJSadYr7SgILVIQ1NTU6@kKDGvOCexJFXDREv94cS@R1P2POpa@mhlY8yjZVvjH3U3P@rZCkQRJ5c@nLT43GyfDxN6O1/NbHnUMf9Rz96Qmkcrp2vaaDxc0aGuyZWZW5BfVKJQlMoVZFuUqldcmvQ/Lb9IoVwhM08hWj2wNDM5W11H3akovzwPSLvlVwBJr9LcgtQUIMO/LLUISIVkpAJJn8SqSiDlkp8OJD1Sc3LyQVKlRSU5qeqxVlwKCgVFmXklGmka5Zqa/wE)

-2 thanks to @MarcMush.
-1 thanks to @Steffan
Test harness borrowed from @solid.py

Comment: @solid.py It's more or less the same trick as [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244180/107561). There is a pretty detailed explanation in one of the comments.

Comment: -1 byte with `R=re.sub`

Comment: @MarcMush I could have sworn I tried that! But then, I can't count :/

Comment: you actually don't need the `r` in `r"\B[AEIUO]\B"`. backslashes are automatically escaped when followed by a letter

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 99 bytes

```
T`L`l
\B[aeiou]\B

(.)\1+
$1
c

T`l`Λ\L_Ꙅ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\\⦵\_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JMEnIYcrxik6MTUzvzQ2xomLS0NPM8ZQm0vFkCuZ68OE3k6ukISchHOzY3ziX81sedQx/1HP3pCaRyuna9poPFzR8XBi36Mpex51LX20sjEm5tGyrTHxj7qbH/VsBaKIk0sfTloMtCQjlSuwNDM5m8upKL88j8stv4LLqzS3oJjLvyy1iAsk7ZNYVcnlkp8OAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`L`l
```

Change everything to lower case.

```
\B[aeiou]\B
```

Remove all interior vowels.

```
(.)\1+
$1
```

Deduplicate consecutive letters.

```
c
```

Convert `c` separately because `T` can only transliterate characters in the BMP.

```
T`l`Λ\L_Ꙅ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\\⦵\_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ
```

Transliterate the remaining letters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras`, 178 bytes

```factor
[ >lower 1 cut 1 short cut* swap "aeiou"without glue [ ] group-by values [ members ] map-concat [ 97 mod "ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ"nth ] map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDNShxBFIX3PsWhQTCBEbIxJBEhEhIUMYSMIDgiZc2d6WK6@/bUj@34s5Bk4T8mBERcuAiKPoC75AGy8R2mlq7yBpM7ShCKW4dzvzocqqW0ZztY@Dwz/@E1lNPGoMU2V96bog1H3UCFJvekxmndW@XQIVtQhpbtwXkrsEPbcihF/UckJZVMx3r43jt0KxjGm5GRbrWJT8HoDqYtVwXe8zpmQ15SEx/XyKKeEubURg/vuI16sD4j1MlatpjB2xzbgyVMZVwJ@gI6eJkuZeuH@jlcpUokigyHpDI@ZQHaWSAsYfmxZG21hzUllhMvp3yVrJNdrsqa5kIrL/arl8i5ieTufO7vydHe/dnXuHsRD3/Xt@LN6bPJsf71bv/bcfzxK@5fxpudRiNe3a7Egy/x8FbO4p/L/vefSSE/8JCLZancDHKjtFSyG7ZJksx0CMnohANqU8CoaxSJAKbwLSE15w8kKZ0O/gE)

- `>lower` Convert to lowercase
- `1 cut 1 short cut* swap` Slice the ends off the input (if possible -- that's what `short` is for) and bring the middle to the top of the stack.
- `"aeiou"without glue` Remove vowels and put the ends back on.
- `[ ] group-by values [ members ] map-concat` Consolidate consecutive letters.
- `[ 97 mod "ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ"nth ] map` Map letters to shorthand characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 76 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
lā¨Ć≠ÅÏžMм}ÔA•6Eˆ2O:¹VÑX©₃Œl±È“v¬BŒŠ>'µ‰‡S“úÁò›ØIÝZÚþв¬èôÏ&Áθ#›¤mн•Ž‚d·вç‡
```

Should have been 74 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) without the `{À`, but apparently there's a bug in `ÅÏ`.. :/

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AZwAY/9vc2FiaWX//2zEgcKoxIbiiaB7w4DDhcOPxb5N0Lx9w5RB4oCiNkXLhjJPOsK5VsORWMKp4oKDxZJswrHDiOKAnHbCrELFksWgPifCteKAsOKAoVPigJzDusOBw7LigLrDmEnDnVrDmsO@0LLCrMOow7TDjybDgc64I@KAusKkbdC94oCixb3igJpkwrfQssOn4oCh//9UdXJ0bGU) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##AegAF/9vc2FiaWX/I3Z5PyIg4oaSICI/ef9sxIHCqMSG4omge8OAw4XDj8W@TdC8fcOUQeKAojZFy4YyTzrCuVbDkVjCqeKCg8WSbMKxw4jigJx2wqxCxZLFoD4nwrXigLDigKFT4oCcw7rDgcOy4oC6w5hJw51aw5rDvtCywqzDqMO0w48mw4HOuCPigLrCpG3QveKAosW94oCaZMK30LLDp@KAof8s/0EgUXVpY2sgQnJvd24gRm94IEp1bXBzIE92ZXIgVGhlIExhenkgRG9nIFR1cnRsZSBPZiBUZXJyb3L/LS1uby1sYXp5).

**Explanation:**

```python
l          # Convert the (implicit) input-string to lowercase
 ā         # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
  ¨        # Remove the last item to make the range [1,length)
   Ć       # Enclose; append its own head, to have a trailing 1
    ≠      # Check which values are NOT 1
           # (we now have a list of 1s with leading/trailing 0 - e.g. [0,1,1,1,0])
     {À    # No-op bug-fix: sort the list, and rotate it once towards the left
     ÅÏ    # Apply to every truthy (==1) character in the string:
       žM  #  Push vowels-constant "aeoiu"
         м #  Remove those from the current character
      }Ô   # After the apply_on_truthy, connected uniquify the resulting string
A # Push the lowecase alphabet
 •6Eˆ2O:¹VÑX©₃Œl±È“v¬BŒŠ>'µ‰‡S“úÁò›ØIÝZÚþв¬èôÏ&Áθ#›¤mн•
          '# Push compressed integer 3279490039691721988310819230336479163628492048784374634744299180010706872685131111164709021133012715753321092552746940878765
   Ž‚d     # Push compressed integer 33189
      ·    # Double it to 66378
           # (compressing 66378 directly is a byte longer: •15Γ•)
       в   # Convert the large integer to base-66378 as list:
           #  [923,76,66377,42564,8735,9021,84,124,10839,41,60,40,6664,5198,9532,8869,10817,92,10677,95,8899,9013,9013,88,613,5283]
        ç  # Convert each integer to a character with that codepoint
         ‡ # Transliterate the lowercase alphabet to these characters
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•6Eˆ2O:¹VÑX©₃Œl±È“v¬BŒŠ>'µ‰‡S“úÁò›ØIÝZÚþв¬èôÏ&Áθ#›¤mн•` is `3279490039691721988310819230336479163628492048784374634744299180010706872685131111164709021133012715753321092552746940878765`; `Ž‚d` is `33189`; `•15Γ•` is `66378` ; and `•6Eˆ2O:¹VÑX©₃Œl±È“v¬BŒŠ>'µ‰‡S“úÁò›ØIÝZÚþв¬èôÏ&Áθ#›¤mн•Ž‚d·в` is `[923,76,66377,42564,8735,9021,84,124,10839,41,60,40,6664,5198,9532,8869,10817,92,10677,95,8899,9013,9013,88,613,5283]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 180 bytes

```python
lambda w:''.join('ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ'[ord(c)%97]for c in(w[0]+re.sub(r'(.)\1+|[aeiou]','',w[1:-1])+(w[-1],'')[len(w)<2]).lower())
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHcSl1dLys/M09D/dxsnw8TejtfzWx51DH/Uc/ekJpHK6dr2mg8XNHxcGLfoyl7HnUtfbSyMebRsq3xj7qbH/VsBaKIk0sfTlqsHp1flKKRrKlqaR6bll@kkKwANLA82iBWuyhVr7g0SaNIXUNPM8ZQuyY6MTUzvzRWXUddXac82tBK1zBWUxuoFEgDhTSjc1KBGjVtjGI19XLyy1OLNDQ1uTJzC/KLShSKUv@DzC4Hmq0Qre4INCKwNDM5G0g7FeWX5wFpt/wKIOlVmltQDKT9y1KLgFRIRiqQ9EmsqgRSLvnpIKHSopIckKh/GoiXWlSUX6Qea8WloFBQlJlXopEGdILmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 103 bytes

Pretty standard approach: lowercase the input, remove the inner vowels, remove duplicated chars and transliterate `a-z` to the required chars.

```perl
$_=lc;s/\B[aeiou]\B//g;s/(.)\1+/$1/g;y;a-z;ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYn2bpYP8YpOjE1M780NsZJXz8dKKChpxljqK2vYgjkVVon6lZZn5vt82FCb@ermS2POuY/6tkbUvNo5XRNG42HKzoeTux7NGXPo66lj1Y2xsQ8WrY1/lF386OerUAUcXLpw0mL//8PLM1MzuZyKsovz@Nyy6/g8irNLSjm8i9LLeIKyUjl8kmsquRyyU//l19QkpmfV/xf17e0JM3iv25BDgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 138 bytes

```julia
~=replace
!s=(lowercase(s)~r"\B[aeiou]\B"=>"")~r"(.)\1*"=>x->["ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ"...][x[1]-'`']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYmxSsNAHIf3/1Okt/QibSC7LRjEQQpFuEHIBT3Sq56ed@GS2ChSEB2qVlERRBwcpGIfoJs@gIvvkBudfIMYf3zL9/32cimYX1TVuGN4IlnMoZF2sNQjbmKWcpy6Y4NoEDIudB7RAHW6CP037LnUX6q1aHdD9P3c@729vvh5OreTFzv9JCd2/ugu4/J9Ut7d2IcPezmz81NK7dtiy16d2emiZvNrVt6/Is/zorAI/ajd3G5G1VAbRzhCOYazgRSKp9gFp15ihMqkwqKFaIZaDeECV4NqBTZyEe9DYPRIwZouYD0/SFLoH3IDZJdDjx0fwareAZKbTHLoD4FwY3T96iwjGjTRhJA/)

Just found out that `~` has the same precedence than assignement (with right associativity so the parenthesis are needed), making it the only operator with lower precendence than `=>`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 80 bytes

```
ɽ:ẏḢṪṪ‡kvF¨MĠvhṅka»⟇†←¬ʁoĊ ∇"₄[ḃ0εẆḭ:₇°ḃτsf≈β→ƈḭ⅛Ṁǒṡ□ø꘍$↲„I₇⊍ǔ¹eṀHbṡ‛1L»»ƛ∨O»τCĿ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvTrhuo/huKLhuarhuarigKFrdkbCqE3EoHZo4bmFa2HCu+Kfh+KAoOKGkMKsyoFvxIog4oiHXCLigoRb4biDMM614bqG4bitOuKCh8Kw4biDz4RzZuKJiM6y4oaSxojhuK3ihZvhuYDHkuG5oeKWocO46piNJOKGsuKAnknigofiio3HlMK5ZeG5gEhi4bmh4oCbMUzCu8K7xpviiKhPwrvPhEPEvyIsIiIsIlR1cnRsZSJd)

Port of 05AB1E answer.

### How?

```
ɽ:ẏḢṪṪ‡kvF¨MĠvhṅka»⟇†←¬ʁoĊ ∇"₄[ḃ0εẆḭ:₇°ḃτsf≈β→ƈḭ⅛Ṁǒṡ□ø꘍$↲„I₇⊍ǔ¹eṀHbṡ‛1L»»ƛ∨O»τCĿ
ɽ                                                                                 # Lowercase the (implicit) input
 :                                                                                # Duplicate
  ẏ                                                                               # Get length range [0, length)
   ḢṪṪ                                                                            # Remove the first item and the last two items
      ‡kvF                                                                        # Two element lambda: Remove all vowels from input to lambda
          ¨M                                                                      # Apply z (the lambda) for each element of x (the lowercased input)
                                                                                  #   only at the indices in y (the length range without the first and last two items)
            Ġ                                                                     # Group consecutive identical items
             vh                                                                   # Get the first item of each (this is removing consecutive duplicates)
               ṅ                                                                  # Join by nothing
                ka                                                                # Push the lowercase alphabet
                  »⟇†←¬ʁoĊ ∇"₄[ḃ0εẆḭ:₇°ḃτsf≈β→ƈḭ⅛Ṁǒṡ□ø꘍$↲„I₇⊍ǔ¹eṀHbṡ‛1L»          # Push huge compressed integer 3279490039691721988310819230336479163628492048784374634744299180010706872685131111164709021133012715753321092552746940878765
                                                                        »ƛ∨O»     # Push compressed integer 66378
                                                                             τ    # Convert the huge compressed integer to base-66378:
                                                                                  #  [923,76,66377,42564,8735,9021,84,124,10839,41,60,40,6664,5198,9532,8869,10817,92,10677,95,8899,9013,9013,88,613,5283]
                                                                              C   # Convert that list of codepoints to their corresponding characters
                                                                               ‡  # Transliterate the string made earlier from the lowercase alphabet to these characters
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 143 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/\B[aeiou]\B|(.)(?=\1)|(.)/gi,(a,b,c)=>c?[..."_ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ"][Buffer(c)[0]%32]:'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1q5Yryi1ICcxOVVDP8YpOjE1M780NsapRkNPU8PeNsZQE8TST8/U0UjUSdJJ1rS1S7aP1tPTU4o/N9vnw4TezlczWx51zH/Uszek5tHK6Zo2Gg9XdDyc2Pdoyp5HXUsfrWyMiXm0bGv8o@7mRz1bgSji5NKHkxYrxUY7laalpRZpJGtGG8SqGhvFWqmra/5XCizNTM5WcCrKL89TcMuvUPAqzS1ITVHwL0stUgjJSFXwSayqVHDJT1fSKy7IySzRUFJQ0tRLyy9yTUzO0ChXsLVTSM7PK87PSdXLyU/XKNcrSExxzUvRsNBU0FZQr7NTUAfSaRrlmpqa/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-pl`, 103 bytes

```ruby
gsub(/\B[aeiou]\B/,"").tr_s!"A-Za-z","ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\\\\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ"*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AbUASv9ydWJ5//9nc3ViKC9cQlthZWlvdV1cQi8sIiIpLnRyX3MhIkEtWmEteiIsIs6bTPCQjYnqmYTiiJ/ijL1UfOKplyk8KOGoiOGRjuKUvOKKpeKpgVxcXFziprVf4ouD4oy14oy1WMml4ZKjIioy//9BClF1aWNrCkJyb3duCkZveApKdW1wcwpPdmVyClRoZQpMYXp5CkRvZwpUdXJ0bGUKT2YKVGVycm9y/m9wdGlvbnP/LXBs)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 99 bytes

```
≔Φ↧θ¬∧∧κ⁻⊕κＬθ№aeiouιθ⭆Φθ¬∧κ⁼ι§θ⊖κyΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ⌕βι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DLTOnJLVIwye/PLUoObE4VaNQU0fBL79EwzEvBYyzdRR8M/NKizU885KLUnNT80pSgYJART6peeklGUD1mkCOc35pXomGUmJqZn6pko5CpiZYtFDTmiugKBMoE1wCpNJ9EwtgFhYibAHa4FpYmphTrJGpo@BY4pmXkloBkndJRbZQE2IkTF7p3GyfDxN6O1/NbHnUMf9Rz96Qmkcrp2vaaDxc0fFwYt@jKXsedS19tLIxJubRsq3xj7qbH/VsBaKIk0sfTloMdKFbJtDmJIhLrYGhkVeSmZJZnFpckpiUk1mcAbI2sSgzMS@zOPe/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Note that the deverbosifier thinks that the embedded string needs to be quoted (at a cost of three bytes) but I disagree. Explanation:

```
≔Φ↧θ¬∧∧κ⁻⊕κＬθ№aeiouιθ⭆Φθ
```

Lowercase the string and remove interior vowels.

```
¬∧κ⁼ι§θ⊖κyΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ⌕βι
```

Deduplicate consecutive letters and translate from lowercase letters to the desired symbols. Note that the symbols take up 3 or 4 bytes each (I'm relying on the deverbosifier calculation here, as it doesn't actually bother generating the appropriate byte sequences).

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 200 bytes

```haskell
import Data.Char
import Data.List
c[h]=[h]
c(h:t)=h:[c|c<-init t,notElem c"AEIOU"]++[last t]
f=map((cycle"ᑎ┼⊥⩁\\⦵_⋃⌵⌵XɥᒣΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈ"!!).ord.head).group.c.map toUpper
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN09k5hbkF5UouCSWJOo5ZyQWcSEL-GQWl3AlR2fE2gIxV7JGhlWJpm2GVXRyTbKNbmZeZolCiU5efolrTmquQrKSo6unf6hSrLZ2dE5iMVAqlivNNjexQEMjuTI5J1Xp4cS-R1P2POpa-mhlY0zMo2Vb4x91Nz_q2QpEESeXPpy0-Nxsnw8TejtfzWx51DH_Uc_ekJpHK6dr2mg8XNGhpKioqZdflKKXkZqYoqmXXpRfWqCXrAc0XaEkP7SgILUI4p8duYmZebYFRZl5JQoqCmkKSiGlRUUlQMsh0jBvAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 289 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s string)(O string){o,S:="",ToUpper(s)
for i:=range S{r,L:=S[i:i+1],len(o)
if L>0&&o[L-1:L]==r{continue}
if!Contains("AEIOU",r)||i<1||i>len(s)-2{o+=r}}
for _,r:=range o{O+=string([]rune(`ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ`)[r-'A'])}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVBNi9NAGMbr_IpsDrszdKrWk4TOQv0CJRClXVhIQxNCUodtZ8Ik8SvNQfSwahUVQWQPFqWL-wN6EOwP2Is_wFtz9ORP8J1kC8PMPM-877zP85x8G8vFzyQIj4JxZEwDLhCfJlJll814mpnLPIvb1_9c2tmSaaa4GKcminMRGjFOjYYh2NneCkn7FjNNOpAHSRIpnBIUS2Vwi6lAwJR-oahtsb7LLd7qeHQSCSwJ4rFh71_d3ZWu3e5YtseYKkIpMi7yqITXnZsAQGCKzd7tu86BSRWZzXi3A9u-_iMl7WuFbDFVlvXAEVXbkbJwWqzRh11P5SLC_u8T-9_7t6_-fnlZHX-t5uvBrDr7TLp48-N48-Fd9elX9XpZnT0fVqerUfXmRTVfwTo8X24-fveJq9p7vT2PlEhFWa5EuU3qSh2MDhITo0BhkEapYTFgErcR4DVHgfyeb4EKnyL_Qc7DI0AwT2vqau6Gko8FcPYQ5oIizd2RT3TVfH2o0b18mqSACUjWYk9XmnUeRUoXgYH5aqiZwcMIiNEMfGpoB8-eAsZg5HypiVtyDBiCGNTVucomdcNwhC9anHj747ouiZSSqi4B2KTNaah9Nnk3tgskLRZjTtB9cJxNBObUCKkhYTEWEui8yG2xaM7_)

Golang, once again, doesn't have the luxury of regexp lookaheads, lookbehinds, and backreferences, forcing a "manual" implementation. If you can find a Golang-compatible regexp that solved this challenge, leave a comment.

A regexp-using solution using `\B[AEIOU]\B` is [10 bytes *longer*](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVBPi9NAHMVrPkXMZWdoWulNsp1D6x9QIlHbhYUkNCFM4rBJJkwSXU17ED2sWkVFENmDRenifoAeBPsB9uIH8NYcPfkR_E2yhYHJe_m937z3Tr9FfPkz84MjP6Jq4rNUYUnGRdHTwqTQVmURdq__udJpSdTT8kKwNMq1_Z4maESPMw0rYZkGaohytf2JkbX7qrg-Noim6ffKvLjBk4zFFHnOyB7eumMduM7Iw72HNIv9gA7jeNyI0IQfZBkVKMe6JrdzoTKDCD8Fh-OKharQTYOMbWawTt_VY5oijvfNQX8247bZ7Rume5WIineImM8b-VQXuwW8sjqkdYdsV5Qp-Pl9av57__bV3y8v65Ov9WIzmdXnn_EAbX-cbD-8qz_9ql-v6vPnTn22ntZvXtSLNZzDi9X243cP26K7N9xz8VwRtChFOt91dq2pRVaKsFopgZ_TXDUIMJndGnDbq1K8oWeAC09XvAclC44AwXvS00ByI8GfpMCZDrwLjiR3mx_LqcXmUKK7ZZLlgDFYlmbP1pK1HlMhhyDAYu1IZvKIAjGdQU4JTf_ZU8AIglysJHGTR4ChiEkzXYoibgTOFF1KrHC3cdOMUCG4aEYAtm0zPZA5277b2JXCDRIihpX7kLiIU8R0NdBVDoeQAIPysrflsr3_Aw) than this solution.

### Explanation

```go
// required import
import."strings"
func f(s string)(O string){
// setup
o,S:="",ToUpper(s)
// for each char...
for i:=range S{
// get the current char
r:=S[i:i+1]
// if it's a duplicate char, ignore
if len(o)>0&&o[len(o)-1:len(o)]==r{continue}
// if it's not a vowel, or it's a vowel not at the start/end of the string, add it in
if !Contains("AEIOU",r)||i<1||i>len(s)-2{o+=r}}
// translate to the unicode chars
for _,r:=range o{O+=string([]rune(`ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ`)[r-'A'])}
return}
```

Answer (score 0):

## POSIX Issue ≤7 Shell + Utilities, 111 characters

```
tr a-z A-Z|sed 's/./&\
/;s/.$/\
&/'|tr A-Z 'ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ/'|sed 2s/[Λ∟⩗┼⋃ɥ]//g|tr -d \\n|tr -cs 0
```

Fun fact: since XPG3, tr is defined in terms of *characters*, and is defined *exclusively* for characters all the way until SUSv3, which renames -c to -C and adds byte-wise -c.
This is why in present-day POSIX we observe -c which renders the first set the complement of specified values and -C — characters, as well as stuff like `[=equivalence classes=]` which IIRC is only vaguely supported by the illumos gate? This is a wide-reaching standards blunder. The status of this in Issue 8 and later is unclear.

Not surprisingly, *nothing* supports this. All implementations behave as-if the data were in the POSIX (C) locale, i.e. they operate on bytes.

For something *actual implementations* accept, substitute the third line for

```
&/;y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/ΛLꙄ∟⌽T|⩗)<(ᨈᑎ┼⊥⩁\\⦵_⋃⌵⌵Xɥᒣ/'|sed 2s/[Λ∟⩗┼⋃ɥ]//g|tr -d \\n|tr -cs 0
```

this is what the transcript below uses to emulate the answer, but it's also obviously much longer.

```
$ for w in A Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog Turtle Of Terror; do echo $w | ./cg; echo; done
Λ
⩁<
L\⌵ᑎ
⌽X
)ᨈ⊥⦵
┼⌵\
_|∟
(ᒣɥ
ꙄT
_\_(∟
┼⌽
_\
```