# Convert To Shorthand Part 2

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, unicode, substitution

[Part 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/246611/convert-to-shorthand-part-1) of the challenge revolved around converting the letters into specific unicode characters.

### Lore

In this part we receive the output from the function made in Part 1, which now has to be arranged in an artistic manner.

### Aim

Take 1 word as input which has already undergone transformation in the function made in Part 1 and perform the necessary transformation

### Example:

A -> A

```
Λ
```

Quick -> Qck

```
 
⩁<
```

Brown -> Brwn

```
L
 \ ᑎ
  ⌵
```

Fox -> Fx

```
⌽
 X
The presence of F's endpoint being in middle can be imagined to be shifted towards right or left. 
That's why it requires a white-space for alignment
```

Jumps -> Jmps

```
ᨈ           ᨈ⊥⦵
)⊥⦵   OR    )

In this case ⦵ has end points in middle, 
hence connection will be at same level as previous symbol
```

Over -> Ovr

```
┼    OR    ┼⌵\
 ⌵\
```

The -> The

```
_
 |
 ∟
```

Lazy -> Lzy

```
(
 ᒣ
  ɥ
```

Dog -> Dg

```
Ꙅ
 T
```

Turtle -> Trtle

```
_
 \_
   (
    ∟
```

Of -> Of

```
┼
⌽
As the widths are slightly different, the joining is approximated.  
The presence of no whitespace before either suggests both to be in same 'column'.
```

Terror -> Tr

```
_
 \
```

### Rules of interconnections

1. The connection must be on the end points of symbol
2. If symbol is drawn next line then spacing must be done appropriately. E.g. showing spacing with `.`

```
_
.\_
...(
....∟

L
.\.ᑎ
..⌵
```

3. The next character must start from it's left/top/bottom most end points and be connected to top/right/bottom most end point of previous symbol

### Visual Representation for clarity

[image: Handwritten Shorthand]
Forgive my handwriting and the error in the image, I have been watching iskall85 a little too much ;p

### Guide For Where To Connect The Next Symbol(The dot represents the connection point)

[image: Drawing Guide]

Comment: Code Golf and iskall85? This is a crossover I never would have expected :p

Comment: That's why I suggested that the Sandbox post should be edited to reflect the 2-part nature. I would suggest that the first part should be removed and the 2nd continue with the output from 1st. Now the overlap between challenges may discourage some answerers.

Comment: @pajonk Thank you! That's a nice way of keeping the questions independent yet connected. I have also edited the sandbox question to reflect the mutli-part nature of the question, which I hope will express the situation better

Comment: This looked like it would be fun to draw. [It was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhJZb.png)

Comment: I can't tell which symbols interconnect in which way. Maybe a table of symbols would help?

Comment: @Neil The symbols connect from their 'endpoints', basically any dangling point so to say. As for the table of symbols, I have given one in Part 1 and I will put a link for it in this question. Are you suggesting a table marking the end points?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant; sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: @Neil No worries. I have added another Image marking all the possible points of connection. I hope this helps.

Comment: @JonathanAllan a white-space is required for this example. The presence of F's endpoint being in middle can be imagined to be shifted towards right or left, depending on it's position as this is a text based challenge. That's why it requires a white-space for alignment.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks for the feedback. I have made the comments in the examples more descriptive to solve this problem.