# Transform characters of your choice into "Hello, world!"

Tags: code-golf, hello-world, open-ended-function

Write a program or function that takes a character as input and outputs a character. Also, choose a list of 13 distinct ASCII printable characters (32-126). When a character from this list is passed into the program or function, it should output the character at the corresponding position in `Hello, world!`. This way, running your code on each element of the list in turn would produce `Hello, world!`.

**Example:**

If your chosen list is `Troublemaking`, you should produce a program or function that maps:

```
T -> H
r -> e
o -> l
u -> l
b -> o
l -> ,
e ->  
m -> w
a -> o
k -> r
i -> l
n -> d
g -> !
```

**Rules:**

- Your score is length of the program/function.
- You can't store any data between program/function runs.
- Include list of the characters you chose into the answer.

Comment: People who downvote, can you share why? (I want to learn from mistakes when I will be making new questions)

Comment: I think this is an interesting puzzle, where it might not be obvious at first to solvers that competitive answers probably shouldn't write "Hello, world!" at all in the their code.

Comment: @xnor Yes, both C and Python answer can be shorter. But can you share why [tag:open-ended-function] should be used?

Comment: I made some edits that I hope make the challenge easier to understand. [tag:open-ended-function] is used for challenges where the solver has the flexibility to choose what the inputs or the outputs of the code are, and it's important to choose well to make your code short. I think this applies here.

Comment: @xnor Thank you for the edits and for the explanation of the tag, I got confused from the official description.

Comment: Assuming that the input character is valid, should the output character always be in the range 32-126 as well?

Comment: @Arnauld No, it doesn't need to be in this range. But if you make two versions where one of them satisfies such property and other doesn't, then feel free to share both.

Comment: You should add a rule the the wrong input will NOT produce "Hello, world" as an output.

Comment: @WalterMitty Can you explain why you think this should be added? (I don't think there is any reason why some other input shouldn't produce "Hello, world!".)

Comment: What about a program that always produces "Hello, world", regardelss of the input.

Comment: @WalterMitty The program can always produce just single character, so it can't output the whole string.

Answer (score 16):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 8 bytes

−1 byte by Sisyphus.

```perl
y;yav;ol
```

Input: `Heavy, world!` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7/SujKxzDo/5/9/j9TEskodhfL8opwUxX/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Comment: `y;yav;ol` works for -1

Comment: Explanation: `y` is character substitution (transliteration) like `tr`, or `sed`'s `y` operator, from one of the set `yav` to the set `ol`.  `y` turns into `o`, `a` or `v` turn into `l`.  Those are the repeated characters in `Hello, World!`, thus the ones that *need* to get remapped so 13 *unique* input characters can produce it.  Nice idea to use this instead of some kind of "hash" function.

Comment: I find it amusing that using `;` as the regex delimiter allows you to remove the otherwise necessary trailing `;`. I'm guessing it's because the `-p` option implicitly adds a semicolon at the end of the program.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 18 bytes

A function that inputs and outputs an ASCII code.

```python
lambda c:c-954%c%3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHZKlnX0tRENVnV@L@3a6SCrUKSukdqTm6@jlJlQVFeiqI6V2JxcWpRiUJOap5GcWqJBlCVpqaCra2CoTFXQVFmXolGUmVJarFGbmKBRpqOAlwabE5Ovo5CeX5RDtAczf8A)

The chosen 13-byte string is: `Helmo,"yprnd!`, and was found using [brute force](https://tio.run/##lVTBbqMwEL37KyapSMyGtpBU2mpJctlL/6HLrgCbYBVMBEZBWvHt2bEJKSRN1fWBGZ6fn4dnxvH9Lo6Pxzsh46xmHNaVYkKqh3RLxlhxCZVC7jRG7hhPhOSQ0MYG2tw3rtVYjWcTUqPS8x8FsVSv3vI58EmchiUo3uD7UwAbmL7wLCscOBRlxiZTB0pe6SmfkMdH@Fnk@1rxCsLfEeQFg/yBoCTsc6pD6IAOURdyG/4SwKFfUAbVPd8Ah1RkHGjUEwwpQQBm4NknLs0KuQP96JBvEIIFuX9eEV6Qwp7iQATb7Xm31jxLrupSaiWftMRUnYdC0r6GpCjBfETjmkJ1XIPnuq5OF4thre9c78T13rnemKtHzvOKK4quO@A6gM7b/ohwFoxRb7X0MaLe8jsm12q9pWmVIjuh8YVY7ybWvzGk2cyEtdkYFgt9@npZMF7XkksFTZxn8wDQzJWWMUDRAcsz8IJAn/NB7syDcWH9BAxIh0FeDnI2yCfz4CMTTrbikXa2rj4w4r@d/Yq7I2GBNDx3oXVXGG/L9rYa6U3XdcJ85UR3mQg@W9j9w5qF@8X@p7yo5OHbbUpLvoZeI3u8Y1RCp0lRS/YDqMUci9nwalXBL4mXRYPH0Hjm0rBv/VztdVO6uiWPx38).

**Alternative Solutions**

```py
lambda c:c^656%c%7    # 18b ('Mahim/!sntjd"')
lambda c:c^308268%c   # 19b ('Z{@HU 2I}B`Y5')
lambda c:c|2242944%c  # 20b ('HeLdi, AoblD!')
lambda c:c^c*2%54%21  # 20b ('Ngchb"+|i{lt,')
lambda c:c-c*c%60%11  # 20b ('Mjmpr-#|tvqe$')
```

Comment: 2 questions: did you write this in C for speed?  also, how did you decide on the form `x-x0%x%x1`?  are there are other forms you also tried?

Comment: @Jonah you can see the other forms dingle tried in the *Alternative Solutions* section

Comment: Doh!  In general, how are you finding the candidates?  Just random trial and error or is it informed by any theory?

Comment: @Jonah Yeah, speed is the main reason I usually use C for brute force tasks like this (and perhaps a bit of personal favouritism). To your second question, it's mostly trial and error. I tried many possible arrangements, but interestingly many were of the form `c OP (something involving c)`. Going down that path eventually led to the final formula `x-x0%x%x1`, and at that point there wasn't much left to try. Then there's the acquired knowledge of knowing what works and what doesn't (a modulo chain with possibly other operators mixed in works well, for example).

Comment: @Jonah: If you had a fixed set of input characters, you could use `gperf` to look for a "perfect hash function", a sequence of math ops that map those inputs to those outputs.  https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html#Motivation  (This is something that's useful for compiler internals, apparently.  And in that case it's often *not* a 1:1 mapping.)

Comment: (correction; gperf is for mapping strings (e.g. language keywords) to different integers in a 0..n-1 range, so normally is 1:1.  But this problem *isn't*, you need 3 different characters to map to `'l'`, for example.)

Answer (score 9):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 14 bytes

```javascript
c=>'lol'[c]||c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAryALkGij7jj7B@JAChhNpQaNLv4d73b/@AvLdt5d5hBrshXtpIhJOVy@DytyvpgiEK/aAYCcI/XcincoY2jkAoc/NQo7iaTRGNh5y1opY@oP)

Input text is:

```javascript
Hel0o, w1r2d!
```

lol

Comment: lol 

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 31 bytes

```
lambda c:c.translate('ll !o'*8)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhb7cxJzk1ISFZKtkvVKihLzinMSS1I11HNyFBTz1bUsNCGqbuoWFGXmlWgoKell5WfmaaRpJGsqpOUXKSQrZOYpqHuk5ijn6yiUKxWppCiqa0I1LVgAoQE)

Input characters to use are `Hel#o, w"r$d!`

Comment: That's a really clever use of `translate`; I didn't know that was possible!

Comment: @Adam just recycling an [old idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244180/107561)...

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 16 bytes

Expects and returns an ASCII code.

Produces `Hello, world!` when given `(a-IK*s]d5P/+`.

```javascript
c=>28+c*c%389%96
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/Z1s7IQjtZK1nV2MJS1dLsf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RrSenp6SRqKup7dWcWyKaYC@tlKsXm5igUaygq2dQnBJUWZeul5aUX6uc0ZikTPQRI00jWS9ZCjHsURDEwj0svIz8zTU1TU1/wMA)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 19 bytes

This version was built such that the output character is guaranteed to be in the range 32-126 as well. The OP has since clarified that this is not required.

Expects and returns an ASCII code.

Produces `Hello, world!` when given `,X=CI:YWx.~7-`.

```javascript
c=>32+c*c*71%193%91
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/Z1s7YSDtZK1nL3FDV0NJY1dLwf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RrSenp6SToSts6dVZHiFXp25rlKsXm5igUaygq2dQnBJUWZeul5aUX6uc0ZikTPQUI00jWS9ZCjHsURDEwj0svIz8zTU1TU1/wMA)

#### Full mapping

```
   | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
---+--------------------------------
20 | M < S B Y = I - 9 m y G H ! r @
30 | 6 T J h S f Q d D L , 4 d l 6 3
40 | c U z l + x 7 y - o # Z i : > u
50 | n ? 8 Y R s a w e   ^ i L W / /
60 | b b / / W L i ^   e w a s R Y 8
70 | ? n u > : i Z # o - y 7 x + l
```

Comment: Very nice answer, can you please also include description how this formula was created or include link for tool or guide which was used?

Comment: you could also do `23+c*c%202%97` with `"4=n6,8.AT\I'` (found with brute-force)

Comment: @Steffan Yes, I got this one as well. Although perfectly valid, I choose the other one because it has neither the backslash nor the quotes, which make the representation of the string (slightly) ambiguous.

Comment: There's also `30+c*c%593%90` with `< &g89ksi^x+%` and `31+c*c%591%95` with `276F=>uAThLaW`. @Jiří I used [this code](https://tio.run/##jZE/b8IwEMV3PsUV8ccmrQWp1A4QFpbuHaNItRKbGJkYOS60ivLZ03MgaUEMHex7sn5@787e8SMvU6sO7qkwmWgaaSwQLRzwDCKYL31dwWLeqiCgUA0AemhvsgVi4fKsVvDqQa879BoOezjsXL3@hQFSU5QOJIIpRGsfH6Ca4RqfQ9oSLq9wg3hVd2d9osLjZ8xTsIpgEb6g8lEmfndWFVsmrdlvcm43ODpRNEE8Tv7r0jXc9cARu@8s0Zv2voDkZAKcHT7LnNzvhHZwfalKAokZY8M3oc0jnGz2MEyYOAr7Tdp3MnGaMC2KrcthjWNc2BY2Vre4VNoJS748j1uET0wvd@jtPEYLps2WfKTRelTxrA7SWToeVf4L6nMNazgpjPvAH7qbt@eHP82VuZKOUMp2RhVkOr0d0u/1oG6aHw) since you were interested.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand the challenge, this answer saves 2 bytes off the naive solution of `x=>"Hello, world!"`?

Comment: @Jonah You need to write a function from character to character, not an entire string.

Comment: @Jonah And you must do so with 13 _distinct_ characters, which is what makes the challenge interesting.

Comment: Yeah the description is clear now after xnor's edit -- I just re-read it.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
“½ṬṚ»y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDex/uXPNw56xDu4H8/x6picl5OgrluUU5KYoA)

Takes `Heacn, wmrld!`. Searched with [this script](https://tio.run/##ZY5BasMwEEX3OsV001iuGnC6M3ifOxgTjC0nCspIjFSEG3J2R@OUYuhKw3/89@XneHH4tUzkbnDV1s5gbt5RhMGN@uT7s1YwmiEahz3N4heSXiZHkMDghu7DheHHNrIOz7UAM4HVWCT5XtVZjdHgtxYQoIHdMc86BcmRHd92AojTtvwxvkhtXR86ldqKX9kJ4FnPsxQy@6y6LF81YU/a237QRelfREEl/5bvZXjIpuEzSO7gWsrHxsj5C@BWly2sYfDvu2vFk8FYJBXksjwB).

```
     y    Transliterate the input by
“½ṬṚ»     "monoclinal".
```

Unless I [brute-forced something wrong](https://tio.run/##bVLLTsMwELznK5YLcUqImiIuUcOFC/8QVchNXDBNbWvXUVQQ3168TloqgXJZZR47O7I7@ndrHk47tAf4UH1/BH1wFj20tlOvTr6pHDrdem2NxGMORJTMDFTnSXuF3tqeTp3agVfkX2nYktd@YCGJrWz3o8Quh51FHrIqAYIa0pew0@YwWuy7mzRhHBxoA2dJIEYmFahcL1slFq6pqvtyk0OZJaB30Csjvhb0ndU1j8TmYKIoDBfHeTWDE2quPYNVuMgPaCL4JxpI0wW/hO2e2e5ydOHQdkPrxaWyplo9LkO@4K6kr1ccaOQ4ROL5N/OYwS2UnIfBNHx3MEY0tSkY63nN2JRVtdpAWDuPRWsH40XapxmsYcX61hqvzaASQD6sWXxqJ8aG2fmsyjYJONRBOGZTzQdJe96A0rwpUcJ6HVMhZbFAhlXHbpvrFpFigSFk1M8HnOmFNhRqEcscYqMT6emphjL2S0Pvg@U/T2TSh86IdcF@IkfzOXc@/4vGW1Ryfzr9AA), a 2-byte compressed string does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞'Ÿ™‡
```

Uses `H2345, world!` as 13 characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc89aM7HrUsetSw8P9/DyNjE1MdhfL8opwURQA) or [verify each ASCII character separately](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX/xb5Rdnk/IiDihpIgIj95/@KInifFuOKEouKAof8s/w).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞      # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 'Ÿ™  '# Push dictionary string "hello"
    ‡  # Transliterate the characters of the (implicit) input-string
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `'Ÿ™` is `"hello"`.

Answer (score 7):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 7 bytes

```
A8 28 75 02 0C 6C C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFRa4MwEH42v@LqGCTTltiyPdR1DDrYXvayp0FbJGqiGRolRqor/etzSVlhJOS4@@6@@@6Ste28yLJpYl0NGD58jBZF1aSsAoHE2jO8M8CqEGhKaWQPpcj7Ut/AkdfoKxJF7lLE157mBhEfSIz4YLhW4G99OCUJM0bLtDc8STDWvGiZrnFECIGsZBoEvpiBxGeEbqTKqj7n8NiZXDaL8gkhqQzUTCpM0Al5zhtgAzSE0ZkYeZd6qdre7Jb3DwcbEQU3Hb6EQrCxEBydIg6y2nH8lz4eYhiDgCDPs67jwQJfIeLSW20bCuzv1TvLSqk4ZE3O177D8gZOVxxu6fLTt5o2GPeqk4Xi@WW@OyLIbgiCg50PjqWsOOARZlb5sF397wD4VkI62rWTvbJMdiHoPE1v/PnlNYRjo6t89pOJihXdNK9XS/vYn9vYYl79Ag)

Using the `regparm(1)` calling convention, this takes an ASCII code in AL and returns one in AL.

Chooses `He@DG, world!`.

In assembly:

```
f:  test al, 0b00101000 # Set flags based on bits 3 and 5 of the character.
    jnz e               # If they are not both 0 (true for all of "Hello, world!"),
                        #  jump to the end, to leave the character unchanged.
    or al, 0b01101100   # Otherwise, set bits 2, 3, 5, and 6 to 1.
                        # (These are the bits that are 1 in both 'l' and 'o'.)
e:  ret                 # Return.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 7 bytes

```
T`d`o-l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JCElIV835/9/j9Qc43wdhXKDIpMURQA) Explanation: Inspired by @loopywalt's Python answer, works by translating `0` to `o` and both `3` and `4` to `l`, so given the 13 distinct characters `Hel3o, w0r4d!` as input the output is `Hello, world!` as desired. (The full transliteration actually maps `0123456789` to `onmlllllll`.)

Comment: So that I remember why I included the `-`, the `o` is normally magic in Retina transliteration, but it's not magic when used in a range. Preceding it with a ``\`` would also have made it nonmagic, but I guess `-` is the more... magic way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>6.5</s> 6 bytes (12 nibbles)

```
=`r\$d:"lo"
```

`"Hel1o, w2r4d!"` becomes `"Hello, world!"`.

```
   \$d          # keep only digit characters
 `r             # and get the value
                # (so non-digits become zero)
=               # and use this to index into
        "lo"    # the string "lo"
       :        # with the input character appended
                # (wrapping around for index >3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
kakH¡Ŀ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwia2FrSMKhxL8iLCIiLCJhXG5iXG5jXG5kXG5lXG5mXG5nXG5oXG5pXG5qXG5rXG5sXG5tIl0=) Takes `a`, `b`, ... `m`

```
     Ŀ # Transliterate
ka     # Lowercase alphabet
  kH¡  # To corresponding chars of "Hello, world!"
```

Comment: @aketon Sentence case, the "w" has to be lowercase

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 23 bytes

```c
f(c){return 656%c%7^c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc1BDsIgEEDRNXMK1DSBRXVl1dR6A69gQgZaxlBqCuiiqUcXa1z@v3lYolO@y7kVKKfRxDR6Xu2rAovDDes5b8ijS9rwc4iahq29AJCP0Cvy4jmQljABWw7HGtjLkjNcvAXyhncmolWjkFICY4/0rx8ka5jzVVnqd6vg412vP9g61YVcLkqDx9MX)

Takes `Mahim/!sntjd"`. Brute forced solution found using [this](https://tio.run/##bVLLboMwEDzjr9hSWbIDaUly6IGk5976AWkqGQPBEQFkSBOa8uulax55SOXgx@zsznpYOZWpyLZtq7IKYiZd5e74WUfVQWegqKS7T@k37aPKZHoII1iWVajyp@SV3EJaZVuDEaxC9kJl7CtXISdnYsW5BmaKn2AFMx@3Jcw8z/PBcU4ckHGl1D2lvqHUPcUyYY1hzzc3mQgNYr1BwH6L0jR34ZjrNHywXZgUV0qwLtV3lMcg4BnG49rbmMRz4xNDvKhLBBdzH3eUn7/gwXEG9b5ajgRjEZxcqHmnYqkYGCswsI/2MtFMuIDNDFLBVTVAVZjCjPOxpDUpLu@xrGBdYFiYxmQPNWRc7jr0@gb/f5dxTPIuXcPPCjG56aqZNtE@TO@jBf6xKmY2HFWVAC2B0RCCuopK/pHZbseB/gvubmMi@nAZExpSHBRKQzMqQ/LA75zqrMKXNKRpf2Wcim3ZTt8Xfw) program.

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 22 bytes

```cpp
[](int&c){c^=656%c%7;}
```

Port of the above.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpLCsIwEADQdeYUo1LJgOLKuoj1Bp5AFMKkn5E0LTbVRalXjwW3j8d9v2dvQ53sGDussEi3u5YQt0wTP4r8mGecncycDGwksB9diWceopPuArBEaK0E/e7EEUygFkE2oD6N@BL1VzMWWJeRG/vSRARKVZpph/34NyYDc7raRtrDagjx6dY/)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc1NCsIwEEDhdeYUo1LIgD8r6yLWG3gFIUxiM9KmYlMtlHr1WHD5vs3jXc2c813zdqRprMpjWXBxurGZ80YiN4PzeO6Tk24fLgASE7RWon534ggmUIsgG1CfII1H/dWMFdY@cbAvTUSg1HP413IhMjDnqw3SHlZ9TA@3/gE "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 9 bytes

- -1 byte thanks to [@Anders Kaseorg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39242/anders-kaseorg)

```bash
tr 012 ol
```

Takes `Hel1o, w0r2d!`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIwcDQSCE/5/9/j9Qcw3wdhXKDIqMURQA)

Comment: −1 byte: `tr 213 ol`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 32 bytes

```
lambda c:"Helo, wrd!"[ord(c)%10]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3FXISc5NSEhWSrZQ8UnPydRTKi1IUlaLzi1I0kjVVDQ1ioer0Cooy80o0lJT0svIz8zTSgLIKaflFCskKmXkKSm7uHkGeXt4-wb4xMX7-SpqaEF0LFkBoAA)

Takes in characters `[F,G,H,R,I,J,K,L,S,M,\,N,O]`.

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 35 bytes

```
lambda c:"Hello, world!"[ord(c)-97]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3lXMSc5NSEhWSrZQ8UnNy8nUUyvOLclIUlaLzi1I0kjV1Lc1joUp1C4oy80o0lJT0svIz8zTSgLIKaflFCskKmXkKSolJySmpaekZmVnZOblKmpoQTQsWQGgA)

Takes in `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m]`.

Comment: Of course, @Arnauld's JS answer also works in Python in 23 bytes: `lambda c:28+c*c%389%96`, but takes 38 bytes if it takes and returns a character: `lambda c:chr(28+ord(c)*ord(c)%389%96)`

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 12 bytes

```javascript
c=>c-954%c%3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBC4IwHMXvfYoliBvkn6CCQiaElw7dPEaHsaZOdLNtGvXll7QO9W7v/d6vZROz3MjBpdPeV9RzmvP0sNvGPN54rpV1yDojVY0oSk6i6/Uqeg5G3ZZJtgh8VPI@irNQtWvmlxIPVAqHg0bAypcIV90J6HSNfwXyjy4AEMQr9GzAHNEclZ8BKqP7omGm0DeBK8yBf8vR4TWZA62WCkcRIZl/Aw)

Using the string `Helmo,"yprnd!`, ported from [dingledooper's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250568/98937)

Expects input as a charcode and outputs as the charcode

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>26</s> 21 bytes

```
"Hello world!"`i$-97+
```

*Down 5 bytes thanks to Razetime*

A port of [Adam's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250558/107017). Takes in `[a..l]`.

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs1LySM3JyVcozy/KSVFUSshU0bU01+biSlNKTEpOSU1Lz8jMys5RAgD84QyD)

Comment: ``"Hello world!"`i$-97+``

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
⭆Ｓ§⁺ιloΣι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaHjmFZSWQLgamjoKjiWeeSmpFRoBOaXFGpk6Cko5@UpA4eDSXI1MTSCw/v/fI9XQxEhHoTy/KCdFkeu/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes as input the 13 distinct characters `He142, world!`. Explanation: Works by mapping `147` to `l` and `258` to `o`.

```
 Ｓ          Input string
⭆           Map over characters and join
    ι       Current character
   ⁺        Concatenated with
     lo     Literal string `lo`
  §         Cyclically indexed by
        ι   Current character
       Σ    Digit value (0 if not a digit)
```

Comment: Your program is supposed to take a single character as input, so you might be able to save a byte by getting rid of the map.

Comment: Actually it would save 2 bytes: [`§⁺θloΣθ`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMOxxDMvJbVCIyCntFijUEdBKSdfSVNHIbg0V6NQU9P6/3@j/7plOQA) but it wouldn't be clear that the program actually works.

Answer (score 0):

### [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 13 bytes

```
O-=cP%%954c 3
```

Port of @dingledooper's answer.

### [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 16 bytes

```
O+28%%^P2 389 96
```

Port of @Arnauld's answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Headascii](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass#Headascii), 45 bytes

```
-----[]]]]]--[]]]][U-]()R-:-()R--:--()R-:R;P!
```

Takes a character and prints it, except for `m`, `n`, and `p`, which map to `l`, `l`, and `o` specifcially. Full chosen string therefore is `Helmo, wprnd!`

[Try It In Headass!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiLS0tLS1bXV1dXV0tLVtdXV1dW1UtXSgpUi06LSgpUi0tOi0tKClSLTpSO1AhIiwiIiwiMTEzIiwiIl0=), which is the same except that it takes character codes as input and returns character codes. Or, run it in Headascii [here](https://replit.com/@thejonymyster/HA23) by pasting this in:

```js
erun("-----[]]]]]--[]]]][U-]()R-:-()R--:--()R-:R;P!","x")
```

and replacing `x` with the character input of your choice.

Or verify the whole thing at once like this lol:

```js
> hellowarp="-----[]]]]]--[]]]][U-]()R-:-()R--:--()R-:R;P!"
'-----[]]]]]--[]]]][U-]()R-:-()R--:--()R-:R;P!'
> verify=x=>erun(hellowarp,x)
[Function: verify]
> "Helmo, wprnd!".split("").forEach(verify)
H
e
l
l
o
,
 
w
o
r
l
d
!
```

#### Explanation

```
-----[]]]]]--[]]]][U-]()R-:-()R--:--()R-:R;P!  full program
-----[]]]]]--[]]]][                            r2 = -108
                   U                           i = input (charcode)
                   U-]()                       if(i - r2 - 1 == 0){       // m
                        R-:               ;P!    print i - 1              // m - 1 == l
                          :-()                 }else if(i - r2 - 2 == 0){ // n
                              R--:        ;P!    print i - 2              // n - 2 == l
                                 :--()         }else if(i - r2 - 4 == 0){ // p
                                      R-: ;P!    print i - 1              // p - 1 == o
                                        :      }else{
                                         R;P!    print i
                                               }
```

Comment: its possible a modulo approach could sneak right under this but i couldnt get it to work so far

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
"0ol"@a|a
```

Uses `Hel2o, w4r5d!`: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbo5S7MLqpaUlaboWK5UM8nOUHBJrEiH8zbUKvgpKHqk5Rvk6CuUmRaYpikoQmQULIDQA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
"0ol"@a|a
     @a   ; Use the input character as an index (if non-digit, treat as 0)
"0ol"     ; into this string (indexing is cyclical: 0->"0", 2->"l", 4->"o", 5->"l")
       |  ; If the result is falsey (i.e. "0"),
        a ; return the input character instead
```